# Why does the Qt Stylesheet "Foo:hover * {" always apply?

Tags: c++, c, qt, stylesheet

I have a list of items which I want to shade the currently selected one. The problem is that the `Foo` widget has children and when the following rule always applies instead of just on hover:

```
Foo:hover {
    background-color:#00FFFF;
}
Foo:hover * {
    background-color:#00FFFF;
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Are you sure that shouldn't be `Foo::hover` ?

Comment: @koan I want both foo and all the children on hover, but the `:fover *` rule is the part thats always matching (even when it isnt hovering).

Comment: In my stylesheet I am using `QPushButton::hover` - note that is 2 colons. If `:hover` is not recognised then it could always match

Comment: @koan just tried it and it doesnt make a difference

Comment: the background colors are the same in your code snipped.Is it on purpose??

Comment: @UmNyobe yes, I want the background of the Foo element and the background of all the child elements to change on hover to the same color.

Answer (score 0):

Your [syntax](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html#selector-types) is wrong. It should be like this:

```
Foo *::hover{ background-color: #00FFFF; }
```

Or if you only want to apply this to direct children:

```
Foo > *::hover{ background-color: #00FFFF; }
```

Comment: This solution will make the children have that color background when they themselves are hovered on. I want their background to change when Foo is hovered on. (I tested this to verify that I am correct.)

Comment: @chacham15 In that case you might have to override enter and leave events and change the stylesheet there.